# Enterprise Keywords TermSet name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-set

I just saw something huge and unbelievable...

I checked my old SharePoint farm, new SharePoint farm, my developer SharePoint farm and also SharePoint Online environment.

Checked now SP2010, SP2013 and SPO. All environments having that problem.

The german translation for the enterprise keyword termset is called:

> **Schüssel**wörter

instead it **should** be called:

> Sch**l**üsselwörter

It is a system term set, so I can't change the name.

Has anyone found the same problem and talked to Microsoft?

Here a screenshot:
[image]

Also in column you see Schüsselwörter based on the term set.

[image]

Comment: Is this really the first strange translation you see in SharePoint? ;)

Comment: :D Of course not, but the word "Schüsselwörter" could be translated in english into "a bowl of words". This word doesn't exist in german, that's the point. ;) And in the description it is right, spelled with and "l" in between.